# PayPal Rest API Invoicing: User is not associated with paypal based on invoicer email

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to use PayPal Rest API to do invoicing. I followed the documentation here [https://developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/). I'm able to get a Bearer Token, able to create a draft invoice but I always get the same error when I try to send the invoice.
I made sure to create 1 business PayPal sandbox account and one personal sandbox PayPal account and I made sure to use in building the invoice the same emails and names as in the profile of those two PayPal sandboxes accounts. I'm getting always **User is not associated with paypal based on invoicer email.** What am I doing wrong please?

Here is my code:

Create Draft Invoice:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A21AALLJG-bj38vBQqmOd18RvmMFGd8KpynK5iN4QitItZ49.....DWi5v191pygpjX7acNugdw" \
-d '{
   "detail":{
      "invoice_number":"#001002003004",
      "invoice_date":"2022-10-05",
      "currency_code":"USD",
      "note":"Thank you.",
      "payment_term":{
         "due_date":"2022-10-06"
      }
   },
   "invoicer":{
      "name":{
         "given_name":"John Doe"
      },
      "address":{
         "address_line_1":"1 Main St, San Jose",
         "admin_area_1":"CA",
         "postal_code":"95131",
         "country_code":"US"
      },
      "email_address":"sb-nunyt18072622@business.example.com",
      "phones":[
         {
            "country_code":"001",
            "national_number":"4086743426",
            "phone_type":"MOBILE"
         }
      ],
      "website":"website.com",
      "logo_url":"https:\/\/website.com\/images\/website.png"
   },
   "primary_recipients":[
      {
         "billing_info":{
            "name":{
               "given_name":"John Doe"
            },
            "address":{
               "address_line_1":"1 Main St, San Jose",
               "admin_area_1":"CA",
               "postal_code":"95131",
               "country_code":"US"
            },
            "email_address":"sb-y47azf21389350@personal.example.com",
            "phones":[
               {
                  "country_code":"001",
                  "national_number":"4089403004",
                  "phone_type":"HOME"
               }
            ],
            "additional_info_value":"add-info"
         },
         "shipping_info":{
            "name":{
               "given_name":"John Doe"
            },
            "address":{
               "address_line_1":"1 Main St, San Jose",
               "admin_area_1":"CA",
               "postal_code":"95131",
               "country_code":"US"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"Yoga Mat",
         "description":"Elastic mat to practice yoga.",
         "quantity":"1",
         "unit_amount":{
            "currency_code":"USD",
            "value":"50.00"
         }
      }
   ]
}'
```

Response:

```
{"rel":"self","href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-5JLL-25MZ-FF2Y-Y2RG","method":"GET"}
```

Send Draft Invoice:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-5JLL-25MZ-FF2Y-Y2RG/send \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer A21AALLJG-bj38vBQqmOd18RvmMFGd8KpynK5iN..........Wi5v191pygpjX7acNugdw" \
-d '{
  "send_to_invoicer": true
}'
```

Response:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 151.101.193.35:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api-m.sandbox.paypal.com (151.101.193.35) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=3014267; C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; CN=www.sandbox.paypal.com
*  start date: Feb  8 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 11 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api-m.sandbox.paypal.com" matched cert's "api-m.sandbox.paypal.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /v2/invoicing/invoices/INV2-5JLL-25MZ-FF2Y-Y2RG/send HTTP/1.1
> Host: api-m.sandbox.paypal.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.65.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer A21AALLJG-bj38.............191pygpjX7acNugdw
> Content-Length: 30
>
* upload completely sent off: 30 out of 30 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 377
< Content-Type: application/json
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Paypal-Debug-Id: c64c32bd383a9
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
< Edge-Control: max-age=0
< Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2022 16:36:41 GMT
< X-Served-By: cache-lhr7321-LHR, cache-mad22050-MAD
< X-Cache: MISS, MISS
< X-Cache-Hits: 0, 0
< X-Timer: S1664987800.334487,VS0,VE666
<
* Connection #0 to host api-m.sandbox.paypal.com left intact
{"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"c64c32bd383a9","details":[{"issue":"USER_NOT_FOUND","description":"User is not associated with paypal based on invoicer email."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors","method":"GET"}]}
```

Comment: Create a new sandbox business account and sandbox REST App for it, try again with that new account -- and if it doesn't work update your question with that new example and **include the new sandbox app's client/secret credentials** so that it can be tested

Comment: Hi, it worked after I followed your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this exact issue. The comment by "Preston PHX" solved my problem. I created new sandbox business and personal accounts, along with a new REST application, and used those when creating and sending my test invoices. It seems like the issue was with the default PayPal sandbox accounts and application.